# Namenode impossible to leave safemode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, safe-mode

We have a big problem with Namenode that does not want to leave Safemode with the following error:

sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave

/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 51: syntax error near unexpected token `export'

/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 51: `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${HADOOP_CLASSPATH}${JAVA_JDBC_LIBS} '

safemode: Call From namenode/10.0.0.4 to namenode:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Any help please ?

We changed all the owner of the files to hdfs and the access to 775 in

var/log/hadoop/hdfs

-rw-r--r-- 1 hdfs hadoop       948 Oct 30 16:11 hadoop-hdfs-datanode-namenode.out

-rwxrwxrwx 1 hdfs hadoop       948 Oct 30 13:22 hadoop-hdfs-datanode-namenode.out.1

-rwxrwxrwx 1 hdfs hadoop       948 Oct 30 13:16 hadoop-hdfs-datanode-namenode.out.2

-rwxrwxrwx 1 hdfs hadoop       948 Oct 30 12:00 hadoop-hdfs-datanode-namenode.out.3

-rwxrwxrwx 1 hdfs hadoop       948 Aug 29 11:16 hadoop-hdfs-datanode-namenode.out.4

-rwxrwxrwx 1 hdfs hadoop       948 Aug 29 10:59 hadoop-hdfs-datanode-namenode.out.5

-rwxrwxrwx 1 hdfs hadoop  21296280 Oct 30 16:11 hadoop-hdfs-namenode-namenode.log

-rwxrwxrwx 1 hdfs hadoop 268463926 Oct 30 12:01 hadoop-hdfs-namenode-namenode.log.1

-rwxrwxrwx 1 hdfs hadoop 268435509 Jan 24  2019 hadoop-hdfs-namenode-namenode.log.10

-rwxrwxrwx 1 hdfs hadoop 268435681 Aug 11 17:12 hadoop-hdfs-namenode-namenode.log.2

-rwxrwxrwx 1 hdfs hadoop 268435701 Jul 18 12:17 hadoop-hdfs-namenode-namenode.log.3

-rwxrwxrwx 1 hdfs hadoop 268435683 Jul  2 18:53 hadoop-hdfs-namenode-namenode.log.4

-rwxrwxrwx 1 hdfs hadoop 268435504 Jun  2 07:52 hadoop-hdfs-namenode-namenode.log.5

-rwxrwxrwx 1 hdfs hadoop 268435570 May 16 04:15 hadoop-hdfs-namenode-namenode.log.6

-rwxrwxrwx 1 hdfs hadoop 268435521 Apr 14  2019 hadoop-hdfs-namenode-namenode.log.7

Nothing on the logs.  The IPtables and the SELINUX are deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running that command only our NameNode? If so, your NameNode process is probably not running at all.

Comment: Yes, the problem only happens on NameNode. All the other nodes can start normally